# DataGridView: DefaultCellStyle working with decimals

Tags: datagridview, format, decimal-point, datagridviewcellstyle

I am using a Datagidview control on winforms. This is getting filled dynamically. I am trying to display 4 decimal format number in the grid. I applied the DefaultCellStyle property as;

```
dataGridViewCellStyle2.Format = "N4";
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle= dataGridViewCellStyle2;
```

When I enter data as 21.2134 it displays it properly. But when I enter a complete number like 20, it shows me number as 20.0000. I want to get rid of those trailing 0's.
Edit:
One more issue just encountered. with this code it accepts data as 21.2100.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance. 
Vijay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try setting the format as

```
dataGridViewCellStyle2.Format = "0.####";
```

This will ensure for upto four decimnal points and would be displayed only if values are present

So in your case it should be `21.2134` and just `20`. When you want to access the values use `FormattedValue` which will do the formatting as specified for the entered value.